# Eclipse Java project error: cannot resolve declaration in swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I get the following error in Eclipse:

```
DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE cannot be resolved something.java javadir/src/ line xxxx   Java Problem
```

`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is in `javax.swing` but even when I add `import javax.swing.*;` it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a fully qualified reference:

```
javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
```

then when you have time, read this section on [static import](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Answer (score 1):

`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is **not** directly in javax.swing.*, but in WindowConstants interface, so you need to use `WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.